# How to pass an asynchronously loaded script to jQuery's getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want a script on my page to be loaded asynchronously and I want some other script loads to be chained to this async load. Meaning only load those other scripts when my first script has loaded.

I can use [jQuery's getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for the chaining requirement but this takes a url as the first parameter. How then can I make my first script async before passing it to getScript? In other words, if I use the below to make the script async..

```
var myAsyncScript = document.createElement('script'); 
myAsyncScript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
myAsyncScript.async = true;
```

How can I give this to getScript when it takes a url string as the first parameter but this is an object?

Comment: `getScript` is itself asynchronous, so you'd just pass the URL of your first script to the first call of `getScript`.

Comment: I did not know that about getScript, you would think they would include it in their docs.

Comment: Well, it mentions that it's an Ajax function...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this:

```js
$.getScript("/myFirstScript.js").then(function(){
    // Once first script is loaded, async load these scripts:
    $.when(
        $.getScript( "/mySecondScript.js" ),
        $.getScript( "/myThirdScript.js" )
    ).done(function(){
        // I get called when all the scripts are loaded!
    });
});
```